# Use reviver function in jQuery.ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have AJAX responses where all `key,value` pairs are quoted. I want to remove the quotes from any values that are numbers. I need to do this globally, for all AJAX requests, with minimal effort.

I am using [`jQuery.getJSON`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) for the majority of the requests, and I want a solution that doesn't require tweaking each of the current AJAX requests individually. (I don't want to add a `JSON.parse(text,myreviver)` call in every one of the existing `$.getJSON` calls.)

For example:

```
Received:    {"age":"31", "money": "-1.329"}
Want:        {"age": 31, "money": -1.329}
```

How can I do this, *for all AJAX requests*?

My current end-goal is to use [`JSON.parse(text, reviver)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to process the data (thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374186/json-parse-using-reviver-function)). I don't know how to hook this into `jQuery.ajax`, though.

I have tried using [`ajaxSuccess()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/), but it doesn't appear to chain-process any data. For example:

```
$(document.ajaxSuccess) ( function(j) {
    JSON.parse(j, myReviver);
}

.getJSON(url, data, function(j) {
    // The data in this success function has not been through myReviver.
}
```

How can I:

- use a reviver function in `jQuery.getJSON`, or
- process the AJAX response in a global `success` function *before* it reaches other success functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could override default text to json converter using [`ajaxSetup`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) "globally, for all AJAX requests, with minimal effort."

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
  converters: {
    // default was jQuery.parseJSON
    'text json': data => JSON.parse(data, numberReviver)
  }
})


$.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(users => users.map(user => ({email: user.email, geo: user.address.geo})))
  .then(console.log)
  
function numberReviver(name, value) {
  if(typeof value === 'string' && /^[+-]?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)$/.test(value)) {
    console.log(`Using custom reviver for ${name}:${value}`)
    value = Number(value)
  }
  
  return value
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I didn't think of that -- I got stuck pursuing the `ajaxSuccess` route. This looks significantly cleaner. I've ended up implementing a `dataFilter`, although that has it's own set of potential problems. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite `.getJSON` with your own method.

The native `getJSON` method can be seen here:

https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.getJSON

```
function (url, data, callback) {
  return jQuery.get(url, data, callback, "json");
}
```

It's a simple enough matter to take the callback passed to `getJSON`, pass your *own* callback to `jQuery.get` with `'text'` instead of `'json'`, parse the JSON using the custom reviver, and then call the original callback.

A complication is that the second parameter passed to `getJSON` is optional (data to send with the request).

Assuming that you always use a success function (third and last argument), you can use rest parameters and `pop()` to get the passed success function. Create a custom success function that takes the text response and uses the custom `JSON.parse`, then calls the passed success function with the created object.

```js
const dequoteDigits = json => JSON.parse(
  json,
  (key, val) => (
    typeof val === 'string' && /^[+-]?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)$/.test(val)
    ? Number(val)
    : val
  )
);
jQuery.getJSON = function (url, ...rest) {
  // normal parameters: url, data (optional), success
  const success = rest.pop();
  const customSuccess = function(textResponse, status, jqXHR) {
    const obj = dequoteDigits(textResponse);
    success.call(this, obj, status, jqXHR);
  };
  // spread the possibly-empty empty array "rest" to put "data" into argument list
  return jQuery.get(url, ...rest, customSuccess, 'text');
};

jQuery.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', (obj) => {
  console.log(obj);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The difference in the snippet output above vs the URL requested

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

is that the latitude and longitude property values have been transformed into numbers, rather than remaining strings.

If you ever use `await` as well without a success callback, then you'll need to overwrite the `then` property of the returned Promise, though dealing with the optional success callback makes the code's logic a lot uglier:

```js
const dequoteDigits = json => JSON.parse(
  json,
  (key, val) => (
    typeof val === 'string' && /^[+-]?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)$/.test(val)
    ? Number(val)
    : val
  )
);
jQuery.getJSON = function (url, ...rest) {
  // normal parameters: url, data (optional), success (optional)
  const data = rest.length && typeof rest[0] !== 'function'
  ? [rest.shift()]
  : [];
  
  const newSuccessArr = typeof rest[0] === 'function'
  ? [function(textResponse, status, jqXHR) {
        const obj = dequoteDigits(textResponse);
        rest[0].call(this, obj, status, jqXHR);
      }
    ]
  : [];
  // spread the possibly-empty dataObj and newSuccessObj into the new argument list array
  const newArgs = [url, ...data, ...newSuccessArr, 'text'];
  
  const prom = jQuery.get.apply(this, newArgs);
  const nativeThen = prom.then;
  prom.then = function(resolve) {
    nativeThen.call(this)
      .then((res) => {
        const obj = dequoteDigits(this.responseText);
        resolve(obj);
      });
  };
  return prom;
};


jQuery.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', (obj) => {
  console.log(obj[0].address.geo);
});



(async () => {
  const obj = await jQuery.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  console.log(obj[0].address.geo);
  // console.log(obj);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```